# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have spring boot project using JPA/Hibernate, MySQL. I have three dao classes that have a many to many relationship.

[image]

The Poko classes look like this

Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_extra",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="extra_id")
    )
    private List<Extra> extras = new ArrayList<>();

  //constructor getters and setters
}
```

ProductExtra

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_extra")
public class ProductExtra {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer productId;
    @Column(name = "extra_id")
    private Integer extraId;

   //constructor getters and setter
}
```

Extra

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extra")
public class Extra {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "extras")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructor getters and setters
}
```

The Extra repository with the query

```
public interface ExtraRepository extends JpaRepository<Extra, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT e.id, e.name, e.price FROM Extra e INNER JOIN ProductExtra pe ON e.id = pe.extraId WHERE pe.productId = ?1")
    List<Extra> findExtraById(Integer productId);
}
```

The mapping in my controller

```
@GetMapping("/product/{productId}")
    public List<Extra>getExtraById(@PathVariable("productId") final Integer productId){
        return extraRepository.findExtraById(productId);
    }
```

I am trying to make a many to many query to select The extras in each product, i am however getting this error `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` the error message surprisingly also contains the results i want. Not sure what am doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `SELECT` clause:

```
@Query("FROM Extra join e.productExtra WHERE pe.productId = ?1")
```

Also keep in mind, that you not write an SQL Query, You work on Object, so for join you use the mapped property