# send query result to view in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a query in which i am returning the list of names based on a condition. The query itself is running fine but when i try to send that to the view i get an error. I am new to spring boot and i unable to solve this query.

This is the error

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<com.apdcl.sop.Model.Feeder>] for value '[Mega Alloy Feeder, Barsapara, Kalapahar, Bishnupur, Industry, North West, West, Bhetapara, Gopinath]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.apdcl.sop.Model.Feeder]
```

This is my repository

```
public interface FeederRepository extends JpaRepository<Feeder, Integer>{
    
    
    
    @Query("SELECT feeder_name FROM Feeder where user_user_id = :userId")
    public List<Feeder> getListOfFeeder(@Param("userId") int userId);
    
}
```

This is my controller

````
public String Test(Model model,Principal principal)
        {
            String officeName= principal.getName();

            User user = this.userRepository.getUserBYUserName(officeName);
            
            int idofuser = user.getId();
            
            List<Feeder> feeder = this.feederRepository.getListOfFeeder(idofuser);

            model.addAttribute("Feeder",feeder);

            return "normal/test";
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
src- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59183862/12732187

```
>    @Query("FROM Feeder where user_user_id = :userId")
     public List<Feeder> getListOfFeeder(@Param("userId") int userId);
```

instead of

```
   @Query("SELECT feeder_name FROM Feeder where user_user_id = :userId")
    public List<Feeder> getListOfFeeder(@Param("userId") int userId);
```

Comment: that worked like a charm..but can you please explain why my sql query was not working??

Comment: I also have no tons of aware about that dear.